# jquery tooltip browser issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can any one help me with the browser issues?
I am using the following tooltip in jquery:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/slide.html

It works great with firefox only.

In IE and chrome the tool tip is not being opened in the desired mode but it opens as a regular tooltip.
In Opera the tooltip appears as a backround image of the page.

did any one face these issues?
Please help me.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="demo">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img alt="" src="https://tsi.nqa-uts.com/Portals/0/details.png" title="<b>Job Desc:</b>[DESCRIPTION]</br><b>Total Hours:</b> [HOURS]" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <a onclick="javascript:ows.Fetch(480,[PAGENUMBER,SYSTEM]-1,'view=[ID]');lxModule(479,false);lxModule(480,true);">[SUMMARY]</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        [CITY]
    </td>
    <td>
        [STATE]
    </td>
    <td>
        [HOURS]
    </td>
    <td>
        [MONTHS]
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>


<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<style>
.tooltip{ 
    display:none; 
    background:transparent url(https://tsi.nqa-uts.com/Portals/0/black_arrow_big.png); 
    font-size:10px; 
    height:150px; 
    width:310px; 
    padding:25px; 
    color:#fff;
    z-index:100;  
}
</style>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#demo img[title]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Thanks 
Sravanthi

Comment: Have you tried making your `<script>` to `<script type="text/javascript">` ?

Comment: Hey Zee ,I tried that too no luck nothing is changed...

Answer (score 0):

Add to the css "position:absolute"

Comment: I did try that too like this :<style>
.tooltip{ 
    display:none; 
    background:transparent url(https://tsi.nqa-uts.com/Portals/0/black_arrow_big.png); 
    font-size:10px; 
    height:150px; 
    width:310px; 
    padding:25px; 
    color:#fff; 
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>    Did not work.Still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem but i solved by adding this property to .ui-tooltip:

```
.ui-tooltip {
    transition: 0s !important;
}
```

Hope it helps.